# Controller action not redirect user is called from AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have controller action which is purpose to Log Off user. It can be achieved with two ways:

- First is when user click on LogOut link on the page which looks like this: `<a href="/MayApp/Account/LogOut">Logout</a>`  It works perfect.
- Second way is when is user in idle (do nothing some time). After some time AJAX call is happened and call controller action like in following:

  $.ajax({
          url: '/MyApp/Account/LogOut',
          type: 'GET',
          success: function () {
              sessionStorage.removeItem('currentTime');
          }
      })

Problem is because second way doesn't work properly. It normally call controller action but controller action never redirect user to login page. User is logged off but it still stay on same page.

I using redirection in following way:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult LogOut()
    {

        // Some Logic

        return Redirect(Url.Action("Login", "Account"));
    }
```

My questions are:
Does it happened if I using asynchronous call?

I also tried with synchronous AJAX call but it doesn't work.

How I can call controller action in different way than with AJAX?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
```

**Edit**

The problem is that because the AJAX call is calling the Logout action, it's the AJAX call that gets redirected. With that in mind just perform a client side redirect using `window.location` in JavaScript.

You could use something like:

```
return JavaScript("window.location = 'http://www.google.co.uk'");
```

or to reload the current page (so any other routing kicks in to say the user isn't authorised to view this page.

```
return JavaScript("location.reload(true)");
```

Comment: Thanks for fast respond. I tried but same thing happened :(

Comment: Take a look at my edit, it provide the reason this isn't working.

Comment: Is it possible without client side redirection. I achieved with this but it not works for me because I use windows azure active directory for login/logoff. It has some "Sign off process page". If I use client side redirection that page will be avoided. I need to redirect in controller action.

Comment: See my edit. It has to be performed via JS but this can still be controlled via the controller.